# NSPathControl to navigate through data structure

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, nspathcontrol

I am programming in Obj-C an application which aim to plot scientific chart. The data which I used are structured like a tree. I would like to use a NSPathControl (or something equivalent) to navigate through the data structure and select the chart to plot.

Is it possible to used the NSPathControl to navigate through data structure ?
How to do it ?

If not possible, which Controller, with similar design as the NSPathControl, can I used ?

Comment: So, you'd like to navigate through your application solely through the pathcontrol? And yes, `NSPathControl` does have full support for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not exactly 'navigate through my application' with an NSTPathControl . The application will read files and each files may contains thousand of plots, organized in a tree like structure. I would like to use the NSPathController to choose which plots I want to display.

Comment: Up to now, when I am trying to use an NSPathControl, I obtain errors: `[_TTreePathController setStringValue:@"path RICH_Eff/hRICHeff_20110904.000000[0]"];` returns me the error `path RICH_Eff/hRICHeff_20110904.000000[0] is not absolute.`which let me think that the NSPathControl search a physical folder on my Hard Drive.